# Execute multiple parallel cURL against the same URL?

Tags: php, curl, soap, parallel-processing, php-curl

I need to execute 2 requests in parallel using cURL to get a reply from the web service.

The problem is that I need to get the encrypted password from the first XML's output and pass it to the second XML to get 100 success response from the API.

Currently, I have created 2 cURL to achieve this but the API responds "101 Password Expired" because the encrypted password is valid only for the first request.

Here is my code for reference:

1st cURL:

```
$soapUrl = "http://localhost:54934/frmMutualFund.asmx?op=getPassword"; // asmx URL of WSDL

// xml post structure

$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                  <soap:Body>
                    <getPassword xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                      <pUserId>12345</pUserId>
                      <pPassword>98765</pPassword>
                      <pPasskey>ksjhdfksj</pPasskey>
                    </getPassword>
                  </soap:Body>
                </soap:Envelope>';   // data from the form, e.g. some ID number

   $headers = array(
                "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                "Accept: text/xml",
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Pragma: no-cache",
                "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/getPassword", 
                "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
            ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

    $url = $soapUrl;

    // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    // converting
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

2nd cURL:

```
$soapUrl = "http://localhost:54934/frmMutualFund.asmx"; // asmx URL of WSDL

// xml post structure

$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                      <soap:Body>
                        <MFUAPI xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                          <pFlag>06</pFlag>
                          <pUserId>12345</pUserId>
                          <pEncPassword>'.$response.'</pEncPassword>
                         <pParam>some_parameters</pParam>
                        </MFUAPI>
                      </soap:Body>
                    </soap:Envelope>';   // data from the form, e.g. some ID number

   $headers = array(
                "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                "Accept: text/xml",
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Pragma: no-cache",
                "SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/MFUAPI", 
                "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
            ); //SOAPAction: your op URL

    $url = $soapUrl;

    // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    // converting
    $response = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);

    // converting
    $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
    $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

    // convertingc to XML
    $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
    // user $parser to get your data out of XML response and to display it.
    print_r($parser);
```

Comment: get rid of `"Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),` - as long as you're using CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, curl will add that header for you automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

first

> I need to execute 2 requests in parallel

then

> The problem is that I need to get the encrypted password from the
>   first XML's output and pass it to the second XML to get 100 success
>   response from the API.

if the request body of the 2nd request depends on the response of the first request, then you cannot do these 2 requests in parallel.

(generally speaking.  you might be able to do some micro-optimization where you send the first request, and partially send the 2nd request, then wait for the password of the first request to be retrieved, then finish the 2nd request, but it'd be difficult to pull off, the gains would probably be very small and if you time it wrong you'll probably get a timeout for the 2nd request and have to start the 2nd request all over again, which would be even slower than just doing the 2 requests sequentially in the first place. you'll also need reliable recovery code for `2nd request timeout'ed while waiting for the password of the 1st request`, it would be easy to code it wrong.)